# Retrieve all Facebook Opened Group wall posts, PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I want to show an opened Facebook Group wall post on my website (normal PHP website) like this Facebook Group Wall Posts:

[image]

but I am just a member of the group.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please refer this link  - `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed`

Comment: Can you give me a clear success example? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Step One: Visit The Facebook Developers Page.

Step Two: Choose Website as Your App's Platform.

Step Three: Create App ID.

Step Four: Retrieve Your Info!

The Facebook SDK for PHP is an open source project hosted on Github. You can get the latest version of the SDK,

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/

Here's the facebook login integration and auth:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login

Then follow this link to get the Group posts

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed